# Create a System.Windows.Media.ImageSource From an Icon File in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am programming in a WPF application in c#. I need to change the notifier icon sometimes;

I implemented the icon like this:

```
<tn:NotifyIcon x:Name="MyNotifyIcon" 
               Text="Title" 
               Icon="Resources/logo/Error.ico"/>
```

My solution is changing the Icon, the type of **MyNotifyIcon.Icon** is ImageSource, and I want to get by an icon file. I could find the way to do that.

Do somebody have some ideas how? Or have the any other solution?

Shortly, I have an address like **/Resource/logo.icon**, and I wanna get a **System.Windows.Media.ImageSource**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `BitmapImage` class:

```
        // Create the source
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.UriSource = new Uri("./Resource/logo/logo.icon");
        img.EndInit();
```

`BitmapImage` class inherits from `ImageSource` class which means you can pass the `BitmapImage` object to `NotifyIcon.Icon` as:

```
NI.Icon = img;
```

Comment: You don't know if the .ico -multi icon file - (or .icon -mono icon file-, he doesn't explain it) have one or more icons in... I don't know if this code doesn't throw an exception

Comment: If the .ico file has more than one icons in it, `Icon="Resources/logo/Error.ico"/>` would throw an exception too.

Comment: @GeorgeChondrompilas what's the type of **image**?

Comment: It's an object of Image class.(wpf control). You will not need it, sorry.

Comment: @GeorgeChondrompilas when I use NI.Icon = img, throws the exception. NI.icon = (System.Windows.Media.ImageSource)img too.

Comment: Can you give me more info about the exception please?

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlParseException: "Unsupported URI syntax. Method expects a relative URI or a pack://application:,,,/ form of absolute URI."

Comment: That means that the `"./Resource/logo/logo.icon"` URI is wrong. Replace it with the correct one.

Comment: @GeorgeChondrompilas I found why, because my icon is frozen.

Comment: Is there anything else I can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the NotifyIcon from the Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification namespace created by Philipp Sumi?  If so you have the option to either specify the icon as an ImageSource or an Icon.

```
TaskbarIcon notifyIcon = new TaskbarIcon();
// set using Icon
notifyIcon.Icon = some System.Drawing.Icon; 
// set using ImageSource
notifyIcon.IconSource = some System.Windows.Media.ImageSource;
```

Note that internally setting IconSource sets Icon.

To set from a resource.

```
notifyIcon.Icon = MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.SomeIcon
```

Comment: Note that only the `IconSource` property is bindable though.

Answer (score 0):

have you thought in do it with resources?

To get from resources:

```
MainNameSpace.Properties.Resources.NameOfIconFileInResources;
```

Put the icons in resources, if you have the image file (not icon) i have a method to change it:

```
    public static Icon toIcon(Bitmap b)
    {
        Bitmap cb = (Bitmap) b.Clone();
        cb.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
        System.IntPtr p = cb.GetHicon();
        Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle(p);
        return ico;
    }
```

And programmatically change it with the known attribute .Icon;
Don't worry about ImageSource type.

Extracting image from icon (.ico) file:

```
Stream iconStream = new FileStream (MainNameSpace.Properties.Resources.NameOfIconFileINResources, FileMode.Open );
IconBitmapDecoder decoder = new IconBitmapDecoder ( 
    iconStream, 
    BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, 
    BitmapCacheOption.None );

// loop through images inside the file
foreach ( var item in decoder.Frames )
{
 //Do whatever you want to do with the single images inside the file
 this.panel.Children.Add ( new Image () { Source = item } );
}

// or just get exactly the 4th image:
var frame = decoder.Frames[3];

// save file as PNG
BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
using ( Stream saveStream = new FileStream ( @"C:\target.png", FileMode.Create ))
{
    encoder.Save( saveStream );
}
```

But you must put the .ico file in resources, or take it with relative path...

Taken from [How can you access icons from a Multi-Icon (.ico) file using index in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742047/how-can-you-access-icons-from-a-multi-icon-ico-file-using-index-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Shortly, I have a string like **./Resource/logo/logo.icon**, I want turn into a type of **Windows.Media.ImageSource** not **Icon**

Comment: Put it in resources! After: ImageSource heritage: ImageSource -> BitmapSource -> Bitmap. You want to do Image from Icon and then cast (or during the process). Icon has method called ToBitmap;

Comment: @DrkDeveloper You can't cast from an Icon to an ImageSource.