# How do I add frames to a ico file? ( IconBitmapDecoder.Frames collection )

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image-processing, ico

Using C# or VB.NET, and under Windows Forms, which for this I'm using WPF library classes to make it easier, I would like to load a .ico file, then I will add a new frame to the icon object, and save the icon object with the new frames added (preferably as a `System.Drawing.Icon` object, otherwise, save it as a new .ico file), simple as that.

For iterating the frames of an icon I'm using the `IconBitmapDecoder` class, I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8742590/1248295) example. However, the `IconBitmapDecoder.Frames` is a `ReadOnlycollection`, so I'm stuck at this point, I don't know which class I need to use to create an icon, adding the frames that I obtained using the `IconBitmapDecoder` class, plus the additional frames that I want to add.

If necessary, bitmap frames (a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame` or `BitmapSource` object) can be converted to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897325/1248295) example.

Please note that I'm very inexperienced using WPF classes.

Comment: See this CodeProject article: [IconLib - Icons Unfolded](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16178/IconLib-Icons-Unfolded-MultiIcon-and-Windows-Vista). The schema presented there is one interesting thing in itself. Also mirrored and updated in this GitHub repository: [IconLib](https://github.com/Jamedjo/IconLib). Also, Hans Passant's take on this: [How to convert an image to an icon without losing transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387391/how-to-convert-an-image-to-an-icon-without-losing-transparency?answertab=active#tab-top). It exposes the Icon's *internals* (in code).

Comment: As you have probably noticed, there's no Encoder for the Icon format, only the Decoder (and if you try to save a Bitmap as Icon using the `System.Drawing` assemblies format, you'll get a PNG file -> GDI+ doesn't support it). But you might be interested in this: [A High-Quality IconBitmapEncoder for WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687057/A-High-Quality-IconBitmapEncoder-for-WPF)

Comment: Also interesting (I think): [Creating and Saving a Multiple-Frame Image - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-creating-and-saving-a-multiple-frame-image-use)

Comment: The article from CodeProject looks great, I will give it a try. Thank you as always @Jimi. Note that the source-code included in the article is flagged as obsolete by the author, who has updated it and moved to GitHub: https://github.com/HerbertLausmann/HL.IconPro

Comment: I'm adding one (partially related) note on this: if you reference a WPF assembly in your WinForms application which is not DPIAware, it will, most probaly, become automatically DPIAware (SystemAware). This can produce (un)predictable differences in the Forms rendering (and size). See these notes on the matter: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Dunno if this can help... I answered a question like this a while ago: [Combine System.Drawing.Bitmap\[\] -> Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54801185/395685)